# Macro \ParametersAGAaAA vs \ParametersAGAa seems to magically interact?

Tags: macros

I have the following example. It's magic because defining a macro ones (\ParametersAGAaAA and \ParametersAGAa) seems to interact to each other. Is this because \ParametersAGAa is part of the string \ParametersAGAaAA? \PutLongTableRows is resetted through \renewcommand{\PutLongtableRows}{} each time before the result is written to \Parameters...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newcommand\PutLongtableRows{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddLongtableRow[2][;]{%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\@gobble}%
    \setsepchar{#1}% LISTOFITEMS SEP CHAR
    \readlist\z{#2}% READ THE LIST INTO \z
    \foreachitem\tmp\in\z{% LISTOFITEMS DO LOOP
        \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\PutLongtableRows
        \expandafter{\expandafter&\tmp}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\PutLongtableRows{\\\hline}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\PutLongtableRows}{}
    \AddLongtableRow{5,1; 5,2}
    \AddLongtableRow{5,3; 5,4}
    \newcommand{\ParametersAGAa}{\PutLongtableRows}

    \renewcommand{\PutLongtableRows}{}
    \AddLongtableRow{5,9; 5,8    ;5,7   }
    \AddLongtableRow{5,6; 5,5    ;5,4}
    \newcommand{\ParametersAGAaAA}{\PutLongtableRows}   

    \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}}
        \caption{Tab 1}
        \\\hline
        \ParametersAGAa
        5,5 &85,6 \\\hline
    \end{longtable}

    \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
        \caption{Tab 2}
        \\\hline
        \ParametersAGAaAA
        5,3 &5,2 &5,1 \\\hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The first table show up nonsense since the \ParametersAGAaAA came up to be written also to \ParametersAGAa. But there was no command to do so. Maybe I have a misunderstanding - however \ParametersAGAaAA and \ParametersAGAa should be independent from each other? Why is \ParametersAGAa overwritten with \ParametersAGAaAA

Comment: TeX offers a macro expansion mechanism. With the first `\newcommand{\ParametersAGAa}{\PutLongtableRows}` you are _not_ giving `\ParametersAGAa` the _present_ value of `\PutLongtableRows` but simply instructing TeX to replace `ParametersAGAa` by `\PutLongtableRows` once it finds it.

Comment: Thx, knowing this it absolutely makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because macro defined by `\newcommand` expands its definition during the macro are used, no during defining. So when you use `\ParametersAGAa` it is equal last definition of`\PutLongtableRows`, that respects `\ParametersAGAaAA`.

To avoid that use internal TeX command `\let` instead of `\newcommand`:

```
\let\ParametersAGAa\PutLongtableRows
```

and

```
\let\ParametersAGAaAA\PutLongtableRows
```

Of course, no any interaction between macros with similar names is possible.